# Outputting a DataFrame instead of Series from a multiple return value groupby-apply operation

Tags: python, pandas

Edit:

I need the apply function that returns several value from several complex calculations. I can return those values in a tuple, and thus the outcome of the groupby-apply action would be a Series with group name as indexes and the tuple as values. I would like it to return a DataFrame instead, So I could keep all the pandas functionality and flexibility.

In general, The outcome of a groupby-apply operation would be a Series In the case apply returning 1 value. In the case of apply returning 2 or more  values, I would like the outcome to be a dataframe. so my question is how to do that. See the original Q for more details and examples

Original Q:

I have a dataframe which contains many columns and groups. I trying to do group-wise operation via the groupby-apply mechanism, and retrive only 2 values for each group. Currently, Im returning a tuple for each group  (e.g. `return (a,b)`) and thus the result Im getting is a series with group names as indexes, and tupels as values.

This is not the best output for me, as I next need to sort by one of this values, and In general this way Im losing much of the DataFrame and Series functionality.

What I would like to get back instead is a dataFrame with columns 'a' and 'b'.

for example, say a have a large dataframe df that look something like that:

```
Out[123]:
         ID1            ID2     score
0    6073165338_1    6073165338  100
1    6073165338_1    6073165338  89
2    6073165338_1    6073165338  87
3    6073165338_1    6073165338  65
4    6073165338_1    6073165338  62
```

I would like to group it by ID1, and return for each group the ID2 (which is the same for each ID1 group)
and the average score of the first 3 entries. I can do something like that:

```
def calc(grp):
    return grp.ID2.iloc[0],grp.score[:2].mean()
```

the results of `df.groupby('ID1').apply(calc)` whould be a series with the ID1 group as index, and tuple with 2 elements as values:

6073165338_1    (6073165338, 94.5)

I want the output to be a dataframe with the same index and a the two values as columns in the dataframe, so I would be able to keep the analysis going easily.

How do I do that?

Comment: A simple example would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the edited question, maybe this is what you are looking for. Returning a series in the apply call results being collated into a dataframe (guessing that is what you are looking for)

Returning a tuple

```
In [721]: x.groupby('ID1').apply(lambda df: (df['ID2'].irow(0), df['score'].irow(0)))
Out[721]:
ID1
6073165338_1    (6073165338, 100)
dtype: object
```

Returning a series

```
In [720]: x.groupby('ID1').apply(lambda df: pd.Series({'c1':df['ID2'].irow(0), 'c2':df['score'].irow(0)}))
Out[720]:
                  c1   c2
ID1
6073165338_1  6073165338  100
```

In te second example, the results are in a dataframe

Comment: I cant do that, since what I get back is not a dataframe. See the edit, I might not been clear enough in the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have two solutions for this. the first one is probably better, still I would appreciate a comment from the expert. first option is to have the applied function return a tuple and then convert the Series of tuples to a DataFrame:

```
s = x.groupby('ID1').apply(calc)
DataFrame(s.tolist(),index = s.index,columns = ['ID2','top3avg'])
```

This results in:

```
Out[156]:
                     ID2    top3avg
ID1     
6073165338_1     6073165338  94.5
```

The second one is to return a dataframe using the dataframe constructor on the returned tuple:

```
def calc(grp):
    return DataFrame([(grp.ID2.iloc[0],grp.score[:2].mean())],columns=['ID2','top3avg'])
```

The result of `x.groupby('ID1').apply(calc)` is now a dataframe:

```
                         ID2    top3avg
ID1         
6073165338_1    0    6073165338  94.5
```

First option seems better since:

1. It runs the DF constructor only once, at the end of the groupby-apply action
2. It does not return the unnecessary integer index.

Comment: added another solution, take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, looks like your example taking average over 2 elements, not 3 - (100 + 89 + 87) / 3 = 92, (100 + 89) / 2 = 94.5.

As for your example, I think it could be done just by getting simple mean() over dataframe where only first 3 rows left for each group. For example, like this:

```
df.groupby('ID1').head(3).groupby('ID1').mean()
```

example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"ID1":['6073165338_1']*5 + [11111] * 6, "ID2":[6073165338 ]*5 + [22222] * 6, "score":[100,89,87,65,62] + [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
>>> df
             ID1         ID2  score
0   6073165338_1  6073165338    100
1   6073165338_1  6073165338     89
2   6073165338_1  6073165338     87
3   6073165338_1  6073165338     65
4   6073165338_1  6073165338     62
5          11111       22222      1
6          11111       22222      2
7          11111       22222      3
8          11111       22222      4
9          11111       22222      5
10         11111       22222      6

>>> df.groupby('ID1').head(3).groupby('ID1').mean()
                     ID2  score
ID1                            
11111              22222      2
6073165338_1  6073165338     92
```

Comment: That's definitely answer the example I gave, but not my problem. which means that I gave a bad example.. Imagine that I need the apply function to retrieve few complex calculations. A function that is not a built-in function. In the case of apply returning 1 value, the outcome is a series. In the case of apply returning 2 or more  values, I would like the outcome to be a dataframe. so my question is how to do that.

Comment: @user1945306 yeah, I see, I'll try a bit later to see if I can come up with some good solution.